# Databinding from a textbox in wpf from separate class in c#

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

New to WPF try to implement a simple textbox binding. Need some help to get this running.

**XAML**

```
<Window x:Class="WPFModel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WPFModel"
    DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <Window.Resources>
        <src:Test x:Key="myDataSource" TextBoxName="Text Init" />
    </Window.Resources>

<Grid>
    <TextBox x:Name="S1" Text = "{Binding Source={StaticResource myDataSource}, Path=TextBoxName, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged, Mode = TwoWay}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="160,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185"/>
</Grid>
```

**MAIN WINDOW**

```
namespace WPFModel
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        Test tb = new Test();

        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            tb.Drawtext();
        }
    }
}
```

**CODE BEHIND**

```
namespace WPFModel
{
    public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string value1;
        public string TextBoxName
        {
            get { return value1; }
            set
            {
                value1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxName");
            }
        }
        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public void Drawtext()
        {
            TextBoxName = "Textbox text";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: FYI: in the Output window of the debugger, you will see error messages from WPF describing binding errors that occur. Had you looked there, you would have seen an error message explaining exactly why the binding failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're setting the datacontext of Window to itself, when instead you should be setting it to the instance of the `Test` object:

```
this.DataContext = tb;
```

Then you can set the binding of the text box to the property on the datacontext object:

```
... Text="{Binding TextBoxName, UpdateSourceTrigger= PropertyChanged, Mode = TwoWay}" ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You are setting your DataContext multiple times. Once in the XAML markup in an attribute of the Window (`DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"`) and again in the code-behind constructor of the Window (`this.DataContext = this;`). In both cases you are not setting the DataContext to instance of `Test`.

You've also created two instances of `Test`. Once in the XAML markup as a resource (`<src:Test x:Key="myDataSource" TextBoxName="Text Init" />`) and again in the code-behind (`Test tb = new Test();`). Then you are binding your text box to the resource instance of `Test`. Since you are calling `DrawText()` on the code-behind instance, the text box in your window never updates.

Instead, what you want to do is have an instance of `Test` as your DataContext of your Window. Since ideally we want to keep the amount of code in the code-behind file (which you were calling Main Window) to a minimum in MVVM the best way to do this would be like the example below. You'll also see that you could use Commands instead of OnClick handlers to call actions in your View Model. If you aren't familiar with `RelayCommand` then check out a simple implementation of it [here](https://gist.github.com/schuster-rainer/2648922)

**XAML**

```cs
<Window x:Class="WPFModel.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:src="clr-namespace:WPFModel"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <src:Test />
    </Window.DataContext>
    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox x:Name="S1" Text = "{Binding TextBoxName}" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="50" Margin="160,165,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="185"/>
        <Button Content="Click Me!" Command={Binding DrawTextCommand} />
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

**VIEW MODEL**

```cs
namespace WPFModel
{
    public class Test : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public ICommand DrawTextCommand { get; private set; }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        private string value1;
        public string TextBoxName
        {
            get { return value1; }
            set
            {
                value1 = value;
                RaisePropertyChanged("TextBoxName");
            }
        }

        public Test()
        {
            this.DrawTextCommand = new RelayCommand(DrawText);
        }

        protected void RaisePropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            var handler = PropertyChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }

        public void Drawtext()
        {
            TextBoxName = "Textbox text";
        }
    }
}
```

**MAIN WINDOW CODE-BEHIND**

```cs
namespace WPFModel
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK thanks lot. Do I need to create a new class for the RelayCommand?
and if I dont want use button events just start from the mainwindow class.

Comment: @ew33 Yes, you would have to create a new class for the RelayCommand (there is an example of how to create it in the link in my answer). If you don't want to use a button to trigger the text change and really want to trigger it from the constructor of the MainWindow then you could call `(this.DataContext as Test).DrawText();` after `InitializeComponent();`.

Comment: Thanks, I will try this.

Comment: @ew33 Sounds good. If it works make sure to mark your question as answered.